# JQuery Sortable list records increment Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am performing drag/drop and sortable operations between two containers from my bottom container im dragging list records and dropping in top container in top container i'm performing sorting operations using JQUERY UI..

All is well between dragging and dropping contents from one div section to another div section but while doing sorting operation my list records are creating duplicate list each time i shuffle list records please somebody help me out in fixing this issue
Thanks!!

**In inspect element i found this bug**

[image]

**Html**

```
<ol id="sortable"></ol>
<ul id="draggable">
    <?php 
        for($i=1;$i<=35;$i++)
        {
        ?>  
            <li id='article_<?php echo $i;?>' class="draggable_li qitem" >
                <div class="main_div">
                    <div class="secondary_div">
                        <div class="form_div">
                            <form>
                                <input style="width:15px;" type="checkbox"/>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item_div">
                            <span class="item">Item = <?php echo $i; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hello btn btn-success">
                        Add to Top Stories
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
   $(document).ready(function() 
   {
    $("#sortable").sortable(
    {
        revert: true,
        refreshPositions: true ,
        helper : 'clone',
        cursor: "move",
        delay: 1,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        revert: 50
    });

    $("#sortable").disableSelection();

    $(".qitem").draggable({
        //containment : "#container",
        tolerance:"pointer",
        helper : 'clone',
        //refreshPositions: true ,
        revert : 'invalid',
        opacity:.4,
    });

    $("#sortable").droppable(
    {
        revert:true,
        hoverClass : 'ui-state-highlight',
        //greedy: true,
        //refreshPositions: true,
        drop : function(ev, ui) 
        {
            $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
            if($(this)[0].id === "sortable")
            {
                console.log($(this).closest("button").find('.hello'));
                $(this).find('.hello').hide();
                $(this).find('.AH_section').show();
                //$(ui.draggable).draggable( 'disable' ); //this will not append dragged list at top of the container
                ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' ).closest('li').prependTo(ui.draggable.closest('ul')); //this will append dragged list at top of the container
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave this here for now since i gotta go, so dont have time to input in the `drop:function()`. It should be straight foward though.

But the issue is you are not suppose to declare sortable and droppable at the same time.

To solve your issue, just add `connectToSortable:'#sortable',` and remove the `droppable`

```
$("#sortable").sortable(
    {
        revert: true,
        refreshPositions: true,
        helper : 'clone',
        cursor: "move",
        delay: 1,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        revert: 50
    }).disableSelection();
$("#sortable").sortable(
{
    revert: true,
    refreshPositions: true,
    helper : 'clone',
    cursor: "move",
    delay: 1,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    revert: 50
}).disableSelection();

$(".qitem").draggable({
    //containment : "#container",
    connectToSortable:'#sortable',
    tolerance:"pointer",
    helper : 'original',
    //refreshPositions: true ,
    revert : 'invalid',
    opacity:.4,
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4n9fn8ou/2/

Comment: Thank you it worked for me but as per my requirement when i drag and drop contents from bottom section to top section i hide dragged items in bottom section and i perform sortable operation in top section and i generate update event please would you help me out it in achieving with connectToSortable it Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for. But, i have updated the answer. See if that is what you want. I dont know what you mean by 'generate update event'